# Asignment in computed getters

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I just want to ask, if it's okey to assign some properties in computed getters?

```
props:
  invoice: 
    type: Object

computed:
  total:
    @invoice.subtotal = { some expression }
```

I want to do this, be cause invoice object is shared over few other components, and those components needs computed data from subtotal component.

Comment: This suggests that `invoice.subtotal` should, itself, be a computed.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not mutate the instance's state inside a computed property.

In your case you should take a look at **[Vuex](http://vuex.vuejs.org)** which is a shared state based on [Flux architecture](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/05/06/flux.html). In Vuex you can have getters and share the reactive state between multiple components...

Comment: But getters only binds data one way (store > component). In my case, I need to save computed value from component to store. For example, invoice store have products array and subtotal attribute, in subtotal component, i would like to collect all products, calculate subtotal and save it on store. And there are a lot of attributes, do I have to write mutator for each field?

Comment: Yes in order to mutate the Vuex state you will have to mutate it via store mutators... how you write them is your own decidion. You can have one mutator for several fields, really depends on what you want to do and achieve.

Comment: I have a lot computed properties. It's a bit strange, I though I could split my component logic over children components. But in the end of the day, it seems I have to define big vuex.store object. So I don't see the difference between big vue component and big vuex.store. :/

Comment: Well your question is strange, you have mentioned you want to share invoice data between components. For that Vuex is the best solution, of course it's not the only one, but is at least painful and right way to do.

Comment: Yes, but not only for output in templates.. I would like to split logic between those components. For example, 'subtotal' children aggregates prices from invoice products. Then 'vat' children, takes data from 'subtotal' and adds some additional fees. Total children takes all data from 'vat' and display in different template. In this way, calculations /aggregations are separated over children components. But if I have to define everything in one big vuex.store object, then I can do same thing on vue component.